# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a very strange issue.
When I open index.html(see below) in the browser, The DOM elements are rendering correctly, but I'm getting this console error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

To make sure the error is not coming from any code in my JavaScript, I emptied my JavaScript file so it had no code in it. So this is not any "code-in-javascript" related issue
What is it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>HAHAHA</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like your javascript file is an html error page. look at the network requests and open up the js file and see what it is

Comment: Maybe you need to check your `index.js` file, maybe you out HTML there.

Comment: @ogranada my index.js is emptied. I emptied it to track down the error source. Its something else

Comment: @JakeGiri if you comment out the <script type="text/javascript" src="./src/index.js"></script>, you won't get that error again, its js related...

Comment: can you write console.log("Hello") into the index.js file and tell me if it still happens?

Comment: @EscOfficial yeah if i comment out the error is gone. but my index.js file in empty. i wiped out js code completely. Its just an empty js file.

Comment: @EscOfficial yeah i wrote `console.log("hello")` into index.js file. The console.log is not executing and still seeing the same error

Comment: So the path `./src/index.js` is not linking to the JS file. So your server says.... redirect it to the index page

Comment: @epascarello sorry i did my typo in reply of your comment and it changed the meaning. I m writting it again.  
i opened up js file in network request. Its "HAHAHA". That is in my index.html. My index.js is empty. How does this happen?

Comment: @epascarello but index.js file is in the `src` directory. And src directory and index.html is on the same level. How can this happen?

Comment: in case you are working with google chrome disabling cache might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development (other browsers may have the same feature)

Comment: Maybe you need to check your server cache policies, because looks like it's not configured as a dev server, that is why your error persists in that way. try restarting the dev server.

Comment: @caramba i did that too. Same issue

Comment: @ogranada yeah that was something with the live-server npm package. May be it was some confirguration thing which i need to tweak but that is beyond my knowledge. So when i used inbuilt live-server extension of vs-code, its working perfectly now.

Comment: You can use the `http-server` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) that allows you to define the cache time `http-server -c-1 . `

Comment: @ogranada I'll look into it though. But strangely I don't know what was wrong with my post that it got downvoted. Its discouraging for me to post again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I figured out the error. I was using npm live-server package. When I used live-server provided by vs-code as an extension, the issue is gone.
It's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 6):

Change the script type to "text/babel" and the error will resolve.

`<script type="text/babel" src="./src/index.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' This error sometimes occurs when someone(developer) puts an Incorrect file path or location of a JavaScript file not only javascript but also a CSS file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).